# struts 2 mapping return List/collection as json

Tags: json, struts2

I have simplfied my code to make it easiear to understand:

I have an action class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  private BigClass item;

  public String myMethod(){
    //call some services
    this.item = processedStuff;
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

and BigClass has an Array in it:

```
public class BigClass{
  private String data1;
  private String data2;
  private List<MyBean> dataArray=new ArrayList()<MyBean>;
  //setters and getters ...
}
```

and the strut.xml mapping

```
 <result name="success" type="json">
      <param name="includeProperties">
         item\.data1,
         item\.data2,
         item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.id,
         item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.name
      </param>

</result>
```

as json result, I'm only getting information data1, and data2, the array is not returning..
however if I change

```
item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.id, 
item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.name
```

to

```
 item\.dataArray.*,
```

I get all the information I need. 
is it the expression `item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.id`  incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

In the struts.xml adding the extra two lines `item\.dataArray,
     item\.dataArray\[\d+\],` fixes the problem. I have also shown it below.

```
<result name="success" type="json">
   <param name="includeProperties">
     item\.data1,
     item\.data2,

     item\.dataArray,
     item\.dataArray\[\d+\],

     item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.id,
     item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.name
  </param>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665243/1448464), and this rejected [Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/284998) :(
And make sure your OGNL expression is correct, both grammatically and logically.
"item\.dataArray\[\d+\]\.id" is grammatically correct, which will get values such as item.dataArray[0].id, item.dataArray[1].id, item.dataArray[2].id and so on.

Comment: Hi, this is long time ago. I couldn't  make it work as just is. what I did is to use item\.dataArray.* and then exclude properties I don't need :/

Comment: @Kossel "excludeProperties" overrides "includeProperties", so your solution works. I am just curious about the MyBean and json result. Maybe you could show us the json result by using your workable solution.