# Json serialization issue when using Struts2-Json plugin

Tags: json, serialization, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have an action class with 3 properties. I am using Struts2-Json plugin to serialize the action class. I am able to serialize the *String selectedCompany* as per my expectations

**The problem**

The **People** `ArrayList<Person>` property is serialized with empty values. I don't seem to find where I have made a mistake.

Json_Response:

[image]

**Action Class:**

```
package json;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

import dao.DataAccess;

public class Json extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8415223624346993447L;
    private ArrayList<String> list; 
    private String selectedCompany = "Buhin Engineers";
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public String getSelectedCompany() {
        return selectedCompany;
    }
    public void setSelectedCompany(String selectedCompany) {
        this.selectedCompany = selectedCompany;
    }
    public ArrayList<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    public void setPeople(ArrayList<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }
    public String execute(){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Yamaha");
        list.add("Hero Honda");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        populatePeople();
    }
    private void populatePeople() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        setPeople(da.retrievePeople());

    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">  
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
            <action name="Json" class="json.Json">
                <result type="json">
                    <param name="includeProperties">selectedCompany,people,list</param>
                </result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2 JSON bean parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17852550/1700321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` are published as array so you need to define the array to be included. like

```
people\[\d+\]\..*,list\[\d+\]\..*
```

If the `List` is the type of objects (instead of simple `String`) you can narrow your result to selected properties like:

```
employee\[\d+\]\.lName,employee\[\d+\]\.fName,
```

If the `List` objects has inner objects you can do as:

```
//The employee\[\d+\]\.address.addressline1 is not enough !!
//May be one can suggest better idea here :)
employee\[\d+\]\.address,employee\[\d+\]\.address.addressline1
```