# Giving an empty json result while executing struts 2 action class

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts-action

Im trying to retrieve data from DB using hibernate ORM and get the out-put as json result using Struts2.
Everything work up to retrieving data from DB, 
but for the json result I get only `{}`.

I think I have done something wrong with my coding. But need some help to figure it out.

> Here is my Action class :

```
@ParentPackage("json-default")
public class SocialIconsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency;

    public List<TiendayaCurrencies> getCurrency() {
        return _currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency) {
        this._currency = _currency;
    }

    @Action(value = "currencies", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"includeProperties",
            "_currency\\[\\d+\\]\\..*"})})
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        _currency = loadCurrencies();

        /*Nothing wrong with the DB results.Just to  test everything works fine.*/
        //for (TiendayaCurrencies _currency1 : _currency) {
           // System.out.println("Title - "+_currency1.getTitle());
       // }


        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private List<TiendayaCurrencies> loadCurrencies() {
        Session session = com.tiendaya.connection.HibernateUtil.
                getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<TiendayaCurrencies> cList = session.
                createCriteria(TiendayaCurrencies.class).list();

        return cList;
    }
}
```

> Pojo class :

```
public class TiendayaCurrencies{


     private Integer id;
     private String title;
     private String code;
     private String symbolLeft;
     private String symbolRight;
     private char decimalPlace;
     ...
```

Is there anything wrong with the includeProperties?(Only place I can think of..) Can any one suggest a way.. I 've tried everything...

> Edit :

```
public class SocialIconsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency=new ArrayList<>();
    private String sample="working";

    public String getSample() {
        return sample;
    }

    public void setSample(String sample) {
        this.sample = sample;
    }
    ...


@Action(value = "currencies", results = {
@Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"includeProperties", "sample"})})

...
```

As json output it gives me : **{"sample":"working"}** which means it works fine. So why it is not working with the *ArrayList*??

Comment: **http://localhost:8080/Tiendaya_Project_Final/currencies**-->(action value) how I execute my action class . It gives me empty json result. **{}-only**

Comment: Aren't you using that JSON result any where ? .. How could you say JSON is empty ? I suspect .. In your JSP or somewhere you are referring to wrong Json List ..

Comment: Before I get result to my JSP , I just check the json object I 'm getting from the server. As I have mentioned above it is empty. So even If I set it to jsp it should gives me an empty html element.(Ex: think about setting it to a choice box )

Comment: `_currency\\[\\d+\\]\\..*` what you want to do with this ?

Comment: `_currency\\[\\d+\\]\\.*` did you try with single dot `.` any way you dont need to use `includeProperties` actually it will serialize all properties in action by default

Comment: with that regular expression I trying to refer all the member variables of **TiendayaCurrencies class** instead of doing `currency\\[\\d+\\]\\.title,currency\\[\\d+\\]\\.id,currency\\[\\d+\\]\\.code,currency\\[\\d+\\]\\.symbolLeft,` ... etc. I think  I should use **includeProperties** to get the json object.

Comment: I tried with given answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648288/problem-with-json-plugin-in-struts-2/5665243#5665243)  . but still getting empty json.

Comment: I tried with **private List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency=new ArrayList<>();** but still the same. Dont know what goes wrong here.Everything looks fine for me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93942/discussion-between-madushan-perera-and-babel).

Comment: its not mandatory to use `includeProperties` .. `includeProperties` is intended to specify particular properties to serialize .. which is like improving performance if you are not concern of performance try with out `prams`

Comment: please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 JSON plugin will serialize your whole action, including all the (non-transient) properties **with a getter**.

Since you are hiding your variables (definitely not a best practice, especially because it forces you to manually write every getter and setter... brr), and you have different names for the variable and for the getter, you are pointing the variable, but **you should point the getter** (then `currency` instead of `_currency`):

```
@Action(value = "currencies", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", 
            type = "json", 
          params = {"includeProperties","currency\\[\\d+\\]\\..*"})
})
```

Also note that you can specify a root object, that is often preferred to the `includeProperties` technique, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265):

```
@Action(value = "currencies", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", 
            type = "json", 
          params = {"root","currency"})
})
```

Comment: Thank u so much man ... You save another day of mine... I was wasting so much time , looking for a solution to this stupid **_currency** word error.Thank you again for the answer. I gonna up vote it again if I could..